# extracting a list of observations from a single sas cell

Tags: sas

I have a sas dataset that has a list of variables embedded within a single character variable, delimited by pipes. It looks something like this:

Obs.  List_of_forms

1,"|FormA(04-15-2003)||FormB(04-15-2004)|",
2,"|FormA(04-15-2002)||FormA(04-15-2003)||FormB(04-15-2003)|"

I would like to extract each of the items delimited by pipes as individual variables, so the data would look something like this:

Obs., form1, form2, form3

1,"FormA(04-15-2003)","FormB(04-15-2004)",., 
2,"FormA(04-15-2002)","FormA(04-15-2003)","FormB(04-15-2003)"

But I'm at a loss for how to do this. I've thought about coding a do-loop to iterate through each pipe, but this seems needlessly complex. Any advice for a more elegant solution?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  If Tom's answer helped you be sure to upvote it.  If it solved your problem, don't forget to mark his answer as the accepted answer (there will be a checkmark next to the voting buttons, press it and it will go green when accepted as the answer).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `SCAN()` function. First we can setup your example data.

```
data have ;
  obs+1;
  input list_of_forms $60. ;
cards;
|FormA(04-15-2003)||FormB(04-15-2004)|
|FormA(04-15-2002)||FormA(04-15-2003)||FormB(04-15-2003)|
;;;;
```

Now we can convert it to multiple columns.

```
data want;
  set have ;
  array form (3) $60 ;
  do i=1 to dim(form);
    form(i) = scan(list_of_forms,i,'|');
  end;
  drop i;
run;
```

To make it more dynamic you could find the maximum number of values over the whole dataset and replace the hard coded upper bound of 3 on the new variables.

```
proc sql noprint ;
  select max(countw(list_of_forms,'|'))
    into :nforms 
    from have
  ;
run;
...
array form (&nforms) $60 ;
```

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thanks!